# Silverlight databinding to locate UIElements

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, find, uielement, uielementcollection

Is it possible to locate `UIElement`(s) on the visual tree in silverlight by inspecting the databinding somehow for a business object being bound. What I want to do is locate elements using a lambda expression (or any other means) from the element being bound something like:

```
var uielements = FindAllUIElements ( (businessObject)=> { businessObject.Firstname; } );
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke to the guys at microsoft
Hammids suggestion was to:
Walk the visual tree and call `FrameworkElement.GetBindingExpression(DP)` for all DPs on that element. The resulting `BindingExpression` class has a property called `DataItem` that you could use to see if you’re interested in that binding.